# postfix relay emails dynamically

Tags: linux, email, postfix

Is it possible to relay incoming emails dynamically with postfix's `relayhost`?

```
relayhost = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/email2server.cf
```

and I used mysql database to query each email with relay host. But did not work.
if I defined `relayhost = myhost2.tld` statically it works.

Am I doing this completely wrong? What is the correct way to achieve this?

Thanks for any answers in advance.

Comment: Please enable statements logging on you db and check what queries are there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use a SQL lookup as relayhost parameter. See the postconf manpage [man 5 postconf](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#relayhost):

```
...
relayhost (default: empty)
       The next-hop destination of non-local mail
...
```

To relay depeding on the recipient email address you have to define the [transport_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#transport_maps) parameter in your postfix configuration. In your case this would look like this:

```
transport_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/email2server.cf
```

[transport_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#transport_maps) overwrites the default relayhost setting. Look in [man 5 transport](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html) to see what postfix expects as SQL query result.

Comment: For some reason my relay server just ignores transport maps. relayhost = xxxx is working fine. But with a transport map nothing! not even error or mail queue.

Comment: It may be that your destination domain myhost2.tld is not allowed to relay mails. You could try to add the setting `relay_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/email2server.cf`. But without your postfix configuration (`postconf -n`) and the mysql configuration (`cat /etc/postfix/email2server.cf`) it's hard to tell what's going wrong.

Comment: Incoming mails are working fine now. Could you please answer my other question. http://serverfault.com/questions/640306/relase-outgoing-mails-to-internet-if-local-delivery-failes - Thanks